# wordpress multiple categories in permanent link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these categories

```
a
- ab
- - ac
- - - ad
```

Posts has many multiple parent categories. Current link looks like this:

> www.example.com/a/post-name

I want to turn it into

> www.example.com/a/ab/ac/ad/post-name

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.25category.25_with_multiple_categories_on_a_post):

> **%category%**
>
> A sanitized version of the category name (category slug
> field on New/Edit Category panel). Nested sub-categories appear as
> nested directories in the URI.

Using your hierarchy, if a post belongs to category `"ad"`,  then the permalink will contain nested sub-categories. i.e. `www.example.com/a/ab/ac/ad/post-name/`.

However, if a post belongs to multiple categories: `a, ab, ac, ad`, then the `%category%` tag will only include the 'eldest ancestor', i.e. `www.example.com/a/post-name/`.

If you want to *force* the permalink structure to include all ancestral categories of a post, then I would look at hooking into [`the_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) and/or [`post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) filters and manipulating the `$url` parameter.